# Ionic 4 - how do I show the results of a request to the html page

Tags: angular, ionic4

In Ionic 4, I'm trying to show the results of a get response.  I get the results of the route, but how do I show that in my html page?

In my license.page.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS}/license`).subscribe(data=>{
      //process the json data
      console.log(data);
      })
  }
```

In my response:

```
Object { site_id: "ABC", side_key: "GWA9TjApcyAKEhnx", license_limit: 1 }
```

I generated a license.ts, but I'm not sure now that I needed to.

```
export interface License {
    site_id: string;
    site_key: string;
    license_limit: number;
}
```

How do I show this information in my license.page.html?

```
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Site ID</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Site Key</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>License Limit</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an ionic list it works over an array, conver the object to an array before the assignment,

declare a variable,

```
sites : any = [];
```

and then,

```
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS}/license`).subscribe(data=>{
   this.sites = [data];
})
```

and your HTML should look like

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let site of sites;">Site ID {{site.site_id}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I tried that, but just getting a blank line on the html page.

Comment: just try {{sites | json}} on the html and see what is the  output

Comment: Its still not coming over.

Comment: can you say what is inside console.log(this.sites);

Comment: "Property 'sites' does not exist on type 'LicensePage'."

Comment: you need to declare that variable as i mentioned above

Comment: That fixed it, I missed declaring that variable, thanks!!